# Adding integers in for loop and printing the total

Tags: ios, swift, loops, parse-platform

I am looping through integer objects and want to add each integer to an integer variable, then when the for-loop is done, print the total. Is there an easy way to do this? Right now, I can retrieve the objects and print them individually, but the total prints as 0 every time.
Please see the code below. This is for an app written in Swift with Parse as the backend.
Anything helps, and thank you!

```
var itemsArray = [Int]()
let followingUserItemsQuery = PFUser.query()
followingUserItemsQuery?.whereKey("objectId", equalTo: (PFUser.currentUser()?.objectId!)!)
followingUserItemsQuery?.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects: [PFObject]?, error) in
                if let objects = objects {
                for object in objects {
                let followingUsersArray = (object["following"] as! [String])
                // Get number of listed items of following users with PFUser query for their total objects
                    for followingUser in followingUsersArray {
                        print(followingUser)
                        let query = PFUser.query()
                        query?.whereKey("objectId", equalTo: followingUser)
                        //Get each user's listedItems count then append to a higher-level integer variable
                        query?.getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock({ (object, error) in
                            itemsArray.append(object!["listedItems"] as! Int)
                        })
                    }
                }
            }
            let itemsSum = itemsArray.reduce(0, combine: +)
            print(itemsSum)
            self.followingUsersAddedItems.text = String("Your followers listed "+String(itemsSum)+" items")
```

Comment: Move your `let itemsSum = ...` into the `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock` and learn more about sync vs. async function

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var count = 0
...
for followingUser in followingUsersArray {
    count += object!["listedItems"] as! Int
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code to reduce / combine the `Int` values is correct. The problem is that it runs before any of  the nested asynchronous Parse queries complete and execute their callbacks. So at the time it runs, `itemsArray` is still empty. You will need to redesign your code so that `itemsSum` is calculated only *after* all the various nested Parse queries have all completed.